# High resolution images do not resize properly when uploaded

Tags: php

When uploading high resolution images such as 3000x3000 or more, the image is uploaded but it bypasses the resizing process, both when using GitHub and PHPImageMagician.

Increasing the settings in php.ini did not fix the issue.

**php.ini**

```
memory_limit:32M

upload_max_filesize:20M  (was 2M)

max_execution_time:60  (was 30)

max_input_time:60
```

Comment: http://www.dotsamazing.com/en/labs/phpmemorylimit 3000x3000=50Mb memory

Comment: Your memory limit may still not be high enough. Consult [**this page**](http://www.scantips.com/basics1d.html) for more information on memory usage. The DPI will also play a role. There's a massive difference between 72dpi and 300dpi, should it be the case.

Comment: @Fred-ii- my link better, its 'dynamic' :-)

Comment: Thanks! Raising the memory_limit fixed it.

Comment: send cash and crumpets!

Comment: No doubt @Dagon But I didn't see it till I posted my comment. Cheers

Comment: I'm "old School" when it comes to pixels ;-) 25 years (in g.a.) under my belt :p @Dagon I should've been a plumber! +1 buddy - will keep that one handy for sure.

Comment: Only thing, that calculator doesn't take DPI into account @Dagon which plays a major role. ;-) which is why "old School", wins again. Ah, my trusty calculator hasn't failed me yet!

Answer (score 0):

May be this is problem of upload image **timeout limit** so I suggest you please **update this value**

1. Go to this Path

   ```
   C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.8\bin\php.ini
   ```
2. Change to:

   ```
   post_max_size = 750M
   upload_max_filesize = 750M
   max_execution_time = 5000
   max_input_time = 5000
   memory_limit = 1000M
   ```
3. Restart WAMP to try again.